# Replace and squeeze boolean feedback columns to single score column in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, case

I have data that looks like this (note one TRUE per row):

```html
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
|ROWS| very_good | good  | neither | poor  | very poor |
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
| 1  | TRUE      | FALSE | FALSE   | FALSE | FALSE     |
| 2  | FALSE     | TRUE  | FALSE   | FALSE | FALSE     |
| 3  | FALSE     | FALSE | FALSE   | TRUE  | FALSE     |
|... | ...       | ...   | ...     | ...   | ...       |
```

I want to replace each TRUE with a number that depends on the column that it is in (5-1), so a score with `very_good` being 5 and `very_poor` being 1, and then squeeze it into one column. So it looks like this:

```html
''''''''''''''
|ROWS| SCORE |
''''''''''''''
| 1  | 5     |
| 2  | 4     |
| 3  | 2     |
|... | ...   |
```

So far I've tried this:

```html
SELECT
...,
(REPLACE(CAST(very_good = 'true' AS STRING),'true', '5'), 
REPLACE(CAST(good = 'true' AS STRING),'true', '4'),
REPLACE(CAST(neither = 'true' AS STRING),'true', '3'), 
REPLACE(CAST(poor = 'true' AS STRING),'true', '2'),
REPLACE(CAST(very_poor = 'true' AS STRING),'true', '1')) AS SCORE,
...,
FROM table
```

But this creates multiple columns and I can't find a way to do multiple REPLACE's within a single column, additionally, this doesn't change the FALSE which needs to be removed. Ideally, I need to deal with some rows being filled with null values as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `case`  expression:

```
select 
    rows, 
    case 
        when very_good = 'true' then 5
        when good      = 'true' then 4
        when neither   = 'true' then 3
        when poor      = 'true' then 2
        when very_poor = 'true' then 1
    end as score
from mytable
```

Note that for this to make sense, only one column in each row should be true - otherwise, the `case` expression returns the highest scoring column.

The following might also work in Big Query, if the columns are of `boolean` datatype:

```
select 
    rows, 
    case 
        when very_good then 5
        when good      then 4
        when neither   then 3
        when poor      then 2
        when very_poor then 1
    end as score
from mytable
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT id, 
  (
    SELECT MAX(TRIM(SPLIT(kv, ':')[OFFSET(0)], '"')) 
    FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(TRIM(TO_JSON_STRING(t), '{}'))) kv
    WHERE SPLIT(kv, ':')[OFFSET(1)] = 'true' 
  ) AS score
FROM `project.dataset.table` t
```

you can test, play with above using sample data as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, TRUE very_good, FALSE good, FALSE neither, FALSE poor, FALSE very_poor UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, NULL, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL 

)
SELECT id, 
  (
    SELECT MAX(TRIM(SPLIT(kv, ':')[OFFSET(0)], '"')) 
    FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(TRIM(TO_JSON_STRING(t), '{}'))) kv
    WHERE SPLIT(kv, ':')[OFFSET(1)] = 'true' 
  ) AS score
FROM `project.dataset.table` t
```

with output

```
Row id  score    
1   1   very_good    
2   2   good     
3   3   poor     
4   4   poor     
5   5   null
```

> Update - looks like I've missed that you wanted to end up with numerical scores - see below updated query

```
#standardSQL
SELECT id, 
  (
    SELECT MAX(TRIM(SPLIT(kv, ':')[OFFSET(0)], '"')) 
    FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(TRIM(TO_JSON_STRING(t), '{}'))) kv
    WHERE SPLIT(kv, ':')[OFFSET(1)] = 'true' 
  ) AS score_in_words,
  (
    SELECT [5, 4, 3, 2, 1][SAFE_ORDINAL(OFFSET)]
    FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(TRIM(TO_JSON_STRING(t), '{}'))) kv WITH OFFSET
    WHERE SPLIT(kv, ':')[OFFSET(1)] = 'true' 
  ) AS score  
FROM `project.dataset.table` t
```

with output

```
Row id  score_in_words  score    
1   1   very_good       5    
2   2   good            4    
3   3   poor            2    
4   4   poor            2    
5   5   null            null
```